# Read value from registry

Tags: batch-file, registry, internet-explorer-11

Normally when I search for a registry value in a batch file I set it up as follows:

```
set regpath="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
set regvalue=svcVersion
set regdata=11.0.9600.17207
reg query "%regpath%" /v "%regvalue%" | find /i "%regdata%"

if errorlevel 1 goto ie11
if errorlevel 0 goto noinstall
```

In this test I am checking for Internet Explorer 11.  This would work perfectly fine if it would only ever be looking for that specific version specified above but if there have been any updates to IE 11 then the value above would be a higher revision.  Is there any way to have it search if something is greater than or equal to instead of just equal to?

I saw an option for "GEQ" but that would be for comparing two values, I'm just searching for that value that may be at least 11.0.9600.17207 but could also be higher than that value.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of a command shell question than an IE question.  :-)

You may already be using the right construct.  According to the XP version of the [IF reference page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490920.aspx) on Technet, errorlevel returns true when "the previous program run by Cmd.exe return[s] an exit code equal to or greater than number."

That particular language is missing from the latest version of the [command-line reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335.aspx), but I would be very surprised if the underlying behavior has changed.

Even if it has, you should be able to use a logical comparison operator.  Both pages contain tables showing the supported operators, as well as examples that combine logical operators with errorlevel.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance